# Keyboard Deselects Field When I Use Caps Lock?

Tags: keyboard

I have a bit of a weird situation with my laptop keyboard (Dell, Windows 7, had for about two years). It's only just started today.

Basically, when I'm typing in any sort of field (Facebook message/status, Google search, this very question box) and I use <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> on a letter, it stops typing and deselects the field!

Using shift has no effect. It's a minor issue, but SUPER annoying. Has my description made any sense, and can anyone help me figure out a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems likely that your keyboard is set up it's possible that something is stuck underneath your keys that is forcing the membrane on both the capslock key and the tab key to be pressed at the same time. This hardware solution could be verified by testing using a different keyboard with this PC via the legacy PS/2 ports if it has them or just plugging a USB keyboard in.

Comment: I think you may be right. I'll try to get some compressed air and see if I can't be sure of that. Since the keyboard is built into the laptop, I would find it difficult to use another, though. :p

Comment: You could plug a USB keyboard into one of the USB ports, many laptops also have legacy PS2 ports. Admittedly it does make it more difficult to use the laptop keyboard with a different device. Answer above is edited to be less generic.

Comment: True enough, but my laptop has only three ports, all of which are actually already in use. :p Thank you for your suggestion, though! I will hopefully get around to fixing it soon.